# Classification of compact globally symmetric spaces

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, lie-groups, riemannian-geometry, symmetric-spaces

It is known that any connected compact Lie group $G$ is a finite quotient of the product of a compact simply connected semisimple Lie group $\tilde{G}$ and a torus $\mathbb{T}^n$ (see for example Chapter V Theorem 8.1 in Brocker). In other words, the universal covering map $\tilde{G}\times \mathbb{R}^n\to G$ factors through some $\tilde{G}\times\mathbb{T}^n$.

More generally, consider a compact globally symmetric space $M$. Then the  universal cover of $M$ is the product of a simply connected globally symmetric space $\tilde{M}$ of compact type and a Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^n$. My question is, is it still true that the universal covering map $\tilde{M}\times \mathbb{R}^n\to M$ factors through some $\tilde{M}\times \mathbb{T}^n$ so that $\tilde{M}\times \mathbb{T}^n\to M$ is a finite Riemannian cover? Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: If $G$ is the isometry group of $M$, then one can deform the given metric to the one that splits off a torus a  finite cover in the way you describe, and so that $G$ still acts by isometries after the deformation, see https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0302221. Perhaps in your case one can show that the deformation must be constant.

Comment: To clarify, you are asking for an *isometric* splitting $\tilde{M}\times \mathbb{T}^n$?

Comment: For not necessarily isometric splitting the answer is yes: Any compact manifold of nonnegative Ricci curvature splits of a torus factor (by Cheeger-Gromoll splitting theorem). But in this case the splitting should be isometric, I think.

Comment: @IanAgol Yes. I think the answer is yes. Now I have a sketch but need to check the details. Write $M=U/K$, and let $\mathfrak{u},\mathfrak{k}$ be the Lie algebras of $U,K$ respectively. Write $\mathfrak{u}=\mathfrak{c}+[\mathfrak{u},\mathfrak{u}]$ where $\mathfrak{c}$ is the center of $\mathfrak{u}$, and then $\mathfrak{k}=\mathfrak{c}\cap\mathfrak{k}+[\mathfrak{k},\mathfrak{k}]$.

Comment: @IanAgol If $\mathfrak{u}=\mathfrak{k}+\mathfrak{m}$ denotes the Cartan decomposition, then the torus factor should come out of $\mathfrak{c}\cap\mathfrak{m}$ and the simply connected factor from  the pair $([\mathfrak{u},\mathfrak{u}],[\mathfrak{k},\mathfrak{k}])$.

Answer (score 2):

See Theorem A here:

https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/2001-129-12/S0002-9939-01-06008-7/S0002-9939-01-06008-7.pdf

Your $M$ is compact globally symmetric so any geodesic is contained in a compact flat.
So you get a covering as you wanted.